# Template Parameter Initialization

Tags: c++, templates, warnings, valgrind

I wrote some  C++ code in which I used Templates. Since I used templates, I could not initialize a couple of template class variables. I got an warning message from valgrind saying **Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)**. So is there a way to get around this and/or initialize template variables?? I couldn't think of a way to do it because even if I initailize them as NULL, when I use string data type a run time failure occurres.

Thank You!

Comment: You will have to post a minimal piece of code, preferably self-contained and compiling (except for the error you're seeing), in order for us to understand what you are talking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a guess what you are asking about, so please ignore it if it's wrong.

IIUC, your problem is that, with template parameters, you cannot properly default-initialize built-ins and user-defined types. The way to solve this is:

```
T obj = T();
```

This works for both built-ins and UDTs.